# save a photo library URL as an NSString then back to URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

what i am trying to do is save a URL to one of the photo library pictures. then use this URL to set the image on a CCSprite.
this is the URL being saved as a NSString :

```
[_currentTarget setObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]absoluteString]] forKey:@"image1Name"];
```

Then set the a property of a Target object i made

```
NSString *image1PathName = [[listOfUserMadeTargets objectAtIndex:num]objectForKey:@"image1Name"];
self.normalImage = image1PathName;
```

this is when the CCSprite is made

```
Target *target = [[Target alloc] targetThatIsUserMade];

[_targets addObject:target]; // add it to the array

target.position = ccp(spawnX,spawnY);

target.scale = -0.001875 * target.position.y + 1.09375;

[self addChild:target z:1];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:target.normalImage]]];

[target setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:image.CGImage    forKey:@"key" ]];
```

The problem im having is that the Target is there, but the image is not

I have done this many different ways with no luck

thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335607/storing-a-reference-to-an-image-saved-in-the-camera-roll) is a post (and answer) I made which shows you how to save the `NSURL` for a `UIImage` in the CameraRoll, and use it later to get the image back, using a `UIImagePickerController`. This [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) should also help you in how to access the image. Hope that Helps!

Comment: i have all that. the problem im having is that the NSURL is not converting to the NSData. when i look in the debugger the data has no bytes