# UIImage encodeWithCoder urecognised selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, core-data

I am getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it. I just added lazy loading from Apple's example (LazyTableImages) combined with the UIImageToDataTransformer class from the Photo Locations sample project.

```
2011-07-08 -[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73af2e0
2011-07-08 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73af2e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02e65919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02fb35de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02e6742b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02dd7116 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02dd6cd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Foundation                          0x02b46076 _encodeObject + 1076
    6   Foundation                          0x02b51495 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 206
    7   CoreData                            0x0098e0f5 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 2677
    8   CoreData                            0x009e00d2 -[NSSQLiteConnection updateRow:] + 354
    9   CoreData                            0x009df084 -[NSSQLConnection performAdapterOperations:] + 180
    10  CoreData                            0x009ded7e -[NSSQLCore _performChangesWithAdapterOps:] + 494
    11  CoreData                            0x009dd876 -[NSSQLCore performChanges] + 406
    12  CoreData                            0x009d7338 -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] + 216
    13  CoreData                            0x00995539 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 409
    14  CoreData                            0x00a4411b -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 3691
    15  CoreData                            0x009cdc48 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 712
    16  Playing                             0x0004b99d -[TheData saveEvent] + 93
    17  Playing                             0x00048097 -[TheData updateEvent:] + 1527
    18  Playing                             0x00047943 -[TheData runUpdateWithData:] + 659
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02dd642d __invoking___ + 29
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x02dd6301 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 145
    21  Foundation                          0x02ba19a5 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 51
    22  Foundation                          0x02b100c6 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 747
    23  Foundation                          0x02b0fd1a ____startOperations_block_invoke_2 + 106
    24  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x924f1fc4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 16
    25  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x924e4292 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 228
    26  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x924e3d21 _pthread_wqthread + 390
    27  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x924e3b66 start_wqthread + 30
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIImage` doesn't conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, and (as such) doesn't implement `encodeWithCoder:`. You may want to convert your image to a data representation (e.g., PNG data) and encode that, instead.

Edit: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072700/iphone-why-does-the-documentation-say-uiimageview-is-nscoding-compliant/1074514#1074514) for a workaround.

Comment: As of iOS 5, UIImage does indeed conform to NSCoding... I'm stuck, however, trying to figure out a solution that works for iOS 4 and 5.