# storing custom_button in NSUserdefaults issue?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsuserdefaults

i am storing my "custom button" in NSUserdefaults using the following code.But i am getting an error "[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" while converting the object to NSdata..here "custom button" is UIButton class. Anyone know why...? please help me.

```
 Custom_button *lock11 = (Custom_button*)[menu1 viewWithTag:100];
                 NSLog(@"opened lock1 ========= %@",lock11);
                 lock11.is_menu_lock_opened = YES; 

                 NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:lock11]; //[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:lock11];
                 [prefs setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"set1lock"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this method into your  Custom_button Class

initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder  for all object

```
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder {

       self = [[CastInnerListData alloc] init];
       if (self != nil) {       
           self.object1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"object1"];
           self.object2 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"object2"];    
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder{

      [coder encodeObject:object1 forKey:@"object1"];
      [coder encodeObject:object2 forKey:@"object2"];
}
```

[For more detail click here](http://my-ios-experience.blogspot.in/2013/11/save-and-retrieve-custom-object-from.html)

Answer (score 3):

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

Objects that don't map directly to property list objects are turned into `NSData` by being sent a coder and encoding their contents. `[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]`. They need to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol for this to work. You will find that `UIImage` does not confirm to the NSCoding protocol before iOS 5. If you want to deploy before iOS 5 you will have to work something out yourself, by implementing NSCoding in your Custom Button class and storing that image in a different way.

Comment: What's the difference from what you are saying to what I posted?

Answer (score 1):

Well a little searching would have given you the answer fast:

[UIImage encodeWithCoder urecognised selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633077/uiimage-encodewithcoder-urecognised-selector)

Comment: UIImage does conform to NSCoding in iOS 5

Comment: And are you sure he is targeting iOS 5 only?

Comment: @Madhumitha buttons contain images within them