# UIImage and NSCoding iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios

Prior to iOS 5.1 if you wanted to use NSCoding protocols with UIImage you had to do something like this.

```
@interface UIImage (NSCoding)

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)deocder;
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

@end
```

Then implement it yourself.  However with iOS 5.1 this generates a warning "Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class" in the .M file for this protocol.  Now if I remove this extension class iOS5.1 will be happy, however this should crash and burn on iOS4.0.  So what is the best course of action?

Comment: This question had already been asked and at that time it was me who answered it - I don't remember which question, because it was back in summer, but I can recall there is a duplicate of this question here.

Comment: Ah, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950173/conditional-categories-in-mountain-lion/11950348#11950348

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same issue, and since it is too late to use subclass rather than cateogry, I followed zoul's suggestion to use class_addMethod, and below is my implementation:

```
#import "UIImage-NSCoding.h"
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#define kEncodingKey        @"UIImage"

static void __attribute__((constructor)) initialize() {
    @autoreleasepool {

        if (![[UIImage class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]) {
            Class class = [UIImage class];

            if (!class_addMethod(
                                 class,
                                 @selector(initWithCoder:), 
                                 class_getMethodImplementation(class, @selector(initWithCoderForArchiver:)),
                                 protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(NSCoding), @selector(initWithCoder:), YES, YES).types
                                )) {
                                    NSLog(@"Critical Error - [UIImage initWithCoder:] not defined.");
                                }

            if (!class_addMethod(
                                 class,
                                 @selector(encodeWithCoder:),
                                 class_getMethodImplementation(class, @selector(encodeWithCoderForArchiver:)),
                                 protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(NSCoding), @selector(encodeWithCoder:), YES, YES).types
                                )) {
                                    NSLog(@"Critical Error - [UIImage encodeWithCoder:] not defined.");
                                }

        } 
    }
}

@implementation UIImage(NSCoding)

- (id) initWithCoderForArchiver:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSData *data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodingKey];
        self = [self initWithData:data];
    }

    return self;

}

- (void) encodeWithCoderForArchiver:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
    [encoder encodeObject:data forKey:kEncodingKey];

}

@end
```

<strike>So far I have not noticed any further issue.</strike> Hope it helps!

**[ATTENTION]**

If you use this UIImage category in order to archive **UIImageViewer** objects, beware that NSCoding implementation of **UIImageViewer** in iOS 5 seems to be broken. The image property of the UIImageViewer is lost after save and load, when it is specified in XIB (I have not tried to see if there is the same issue when UIImageViewer object is being created in code). This has been fixed in iOS 6.

**[UPDATES]**

I changed my code to add methods in +load instead initialize(), it is still being executed only once, but earlier. My current implementation:

```
#import "UIImage+NSCoding.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#define kEncodingKey        @"UIImage"

@implementation UIImage (NSCoding)

+ (void) load
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        if (![UIImage conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]) {
            Class class = [UIImage class];
            if (!class_addMethod(
                                 class,
                                 @selector(initWithCoder:), 
                                 class_getMethodImplementation(class, @selector(initWithCoderForArchiver:)),
                                 protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(NSCoding), @selector(initWithCoder:), YES, YES).types
                                 )) {
                NSLog(@"Critical Error - [UIImage initWithCoder:] not defined.");
            }

            if (!class_addMethod(
                                 class,
                                 @selector(encodeWithCoder:),
                                 class_getMethodImplementation(class, @selector(encodeWithCoderForArchiver:)),
                                 protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(NSCoding), @selector(encodeWithCoder:), YES, YES).types
                                 )) {
                NSLog(@"Critical Error - [UIImage encodeWithCoder:] not defined.");
            }

        } 
    }
}

- (id) initWithCoderForArchiver:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSData *data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodingKey];
        self = [self initWithData:data];
    }

    return self;

}

- (void) encodeWithCoderForArchiver:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
    [encoder encodeObject:data forKey:kEncodingKey];

}

@end
```

Comment: Would you mind providing some context as to where this code would go? I have a custom object class that contains 2 NSStrings and a UIImage, would it go in there?

Comment: The above code is implemented as category of UIImage. Basically what I have done is just extending what Jeff LaMarche have implemented (http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/03/uiimage-and-nscoding.html) to avoid having warning message in iOS 5.1.

Comment: `[[UIImage class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]` can be written as `[UIImage conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]`

Comment: will this correctly save and load the image's `scale` property?

Comment: you are calling `init` twice on the same object in the `initWithCoderForArchiver` method

Comment: @user102008 How did you manage to trace that init is being called twice? The scale property of the image is being save and load correctly in my project.

Comment: @user102008, you are right. I just copied the method from Jeff LaMarche and using it for so long without realizing it!

Comment: So this bit 
    **if (![UIImage conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]) 
        {
           //stuff
        }**

on my iPhone 3gs which is ios 4.3...skips over it completely and then later has a go at me about UIimage not responding to encodeObject...Am i using this category wrong? to make it work i have to use a **@try @catch @finally** and explicitly call **encodeWithCoderForArchiver**

Comment: @Genhain It is strange as it should NOT skip in ios 4.3. If not mistaken, the protocol is implemented in ios 5.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a category on UIImage, wouldn't it be cleaner to subclass it?

Then you could implement `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder` and use UIImage's NSCoding implementation on 5.1 and your own on pre-5.1.

Comment: There is only one place I need to save a UIImage, subclassing will require me to always use this new Image class I have invented.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to dynamically patch the `UIImage` class to add the needed methods when running on iOS 4 (or better, when the methods are missing). [Here’s a sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/SFContainerViewController) that does something similar, it adds controller containment support for iOS 4 (the key is the `class_addMethod` function). But this is too much magic for production code, so if there’s a simpler answer, go with it.

Comment: Mucking with classes using the runtime is brittle, it’s hard to foresee the problems that might arise.