# How to avoid accidental overriding method or property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For instance, I subclassed `UILabel` and added a method or property called `-verticalTextAlignment` to align text vertically.
And in the future, if next version of SDK or iOS added a method or property which has the same name, then it is possible my app crashs or behaves unexpectedly.

*This problem happens even if you use category instead of subclassing.

**Question1**
How to avoid this kind of accidental overriding in Objective-C?
I think you can avoid this by prefixing all of your methods and properties like `-XXX_verticalTextAlignment`. But it is not realistic, is it?

**Question2**
I know that this kind of accidental overriding happens at compiling time or when you update your iOS SDK, OSX SDK, or XCode.

But is it possible to happen also when updating your iPhone's iOS version?
For example, is it possible that your app runs well on iOS5 but doesn't run on iOS6 due to accidental overriding in iOS6.(You can replace iOS5 and iOS6 with any versions, for example iOS5.0 and iOS5.1)

Comment: You can also load the method conditionally - see my answer. Btw, +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes you *could* use your own prefix, however that is uncommon.
2. Yes, it can happen after an O/S update; Objective-C is a very dynamic language where messages are sent to methods rather than being called, as in other languages.  These things are worked-out at runtime, not compile time.

Bottom line is yes, you might accidentally override a future base class method and the only solution is to be there when it happens and rename the method.

Comment: Prefixing is becoming more and more popular as Objective C and Cocoa programming popularity is growing and people's investment in their code can't allow for potential namespace conflicts. But as you said, it's uncommon on a base level.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks. Does that mean you have to be worried about accidental overriding all the time and have to test all of your apps every time new iOS or OSX versions are released? In that case, I wanna prefix every thing. But how often have you seen the source code which every methods and properties are prefixed? (I have never seen the code like that.)

Comment: @js_ Yes if you are really worried about it then prefixing is your only defense.  However I haven't seen prefixing in anything other than *library code* where it's used to avoid clashes with the user's code.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks. Could you tell me the library's name if possible? I wanna see it.

Comment: Dave Dribbin is doing it since ages: https://bitbucket.org/ddribin/ddfoundation/ I'm even calling them "Dribbin Prefixes". In one blog post he mentions that Apple is aware of this problem since the beginning of time: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2010/03/02/what_i_miss_from_java/

Comment: thank you @NikolaiRuhe and trojanfoe for good examples and information. I decided to prefix everything. I know prefixing every methods and properties is crazy but it is not very painful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing your category methods are the safest way to avoid these conflicts in an every growing, non namespaced cocoa ecosystem.

It's quite valid and reasonable that framework creators, open source developers and other individual developers should prefix their class methods.

Quite often I write methods prefixed with my company initials, then continue with the method.

```
- (void)JCMyMethodNamedSimilarToBaseClass;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Do you prefix not only `category mothods` and `class methods` but also all instance methods and properties of subclass(not category)?
And do you prefix your custom class?(that is subclass of NSObject. So it is possible to accidentally override NSObject's method or property in the future)

Comment: @js_ I would prefix subclasses of Cocoa framework classes (UIAlertView, etc.), but I don't prefix custom NSObject subclasses' instance or class methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1a Category**

Use a prefix, or avoid the whole mess and use functions instead.

**Question 1b Subclass Methods**

If a method does something general enough that the superclass may also implement it, I simply choose a method name which is a little more 'wordy' than Apple would conventionally choose -- such as specifying a non standard typename in the method's name. Of course, this only *reduces* the possibility of collision.

If you need a higher level of security, you could just test this at execution (so you know when they are introduced) and hope every user stays up to date -- or you could rely on C and/or C++ more heavily (they do not have this problem).

**Question 2**

> But is it possible to happen also when updating your iPhone's iOS version?

Yes. It's not so unusual. When the frameworks are updated (e.g. via software update), they may contain updated frameworks. This code is loaded into the objc runtime, and you always get the version of the installed frameworks' objc implementations.

It's also a much broader problem on OS X, where you may load code and/or plugins dynamically quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution is to check for the method being already there and only adding it if it isn't: [Conditional categories in Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950173/conditional-categories-in-mountain-lion/11950348#11950348)

Comment: thanks! The question you linked is good example of accidental overriding I worried about. But I think class_addMethod doesn't solve future accidental overriding, but it's useful information.

Comment: Neither is this an elegant nor a practical approach to solve the problem of overriding future methods.

Comment: @js_ why doesn't it? It's not class_addMethod in itself that solves the problem - it's actually the check for the method being already there.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe why isn't it? Then suggest a better one instead of being ironic (apparently you didn't provide a useful answer, not even any answer...)

Comment: @H2CO3 This proposal only suppresses *expected* name clashes. The question was about *accidental* overriding of methods. Your code has several disadvantages, like possible argument type incompatibility, and the ugly hackery with the runtime. But the main concern is that is does not fix name clashes in the way namespaces would. Your method might just do something else than the (future) framework method.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I still don't see your concrete solution in an answer. "ugly runtime hackery" - what do you think, why the runtime functions are there?