# Objective-C private function unintended overload in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Background:

About 2 yrs back, I had added a function to UIView category named "removeAllGestures" (or something similar), then iOS update happened, and they added a private function to UIView named the same thing -- and it ended up calling my function unexpectedly; so it broke the app.

That's fair. I was supposed to prepend all category functions with jn_ (i.e. jn_removeAllGestures). I should've and fixed it.

However, wouldn't the same thing had happened if I had my own JNView (subclass of UIView), and had added "removeAllGestures" to that subclass? (assuming I use JNView wherever I was to use UIView).

Nobody so far has recommended (to my knowledge) to prepend *all* function names with 2-letter ids yet; but it seems almost it's necessary?

The gripe I have is, because obj-c doesn't make you declare private functions in the header, it's very possible to collide with them unintentionally.

Comment: Partially answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049763/how-to-avoid-accidental-overriding-method-or-property-in-objective-c